# Python complex dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

My question pertains to dictionary keys. I want to set up a dictionary that has 3 keys for any single object. The keys must be in order and can have a wide range of values. For instance,

```
dictionary = {(key1,key2,key3) : object}
```

key1 can be any value between 1 and 10
key2 can be any value between 11 and 20
key3 can be any value between 21 and 30

The order in which the keys are placed does matter.

More specifically, my keys correspond to a range of x,y,z cartesian coordinates in which many objects are floating around in. I want to be able to sort the relative position of the objects based off their x,y,z positions.

Is there any way to set this up or will I have to take a different approach?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Should be possible, I think. Why don't you try?

Comment: Looks like your example is what you should try. Just make the tuple the key

Comment: Be careful that a dictionary is actually what you want, since it implies that no two objects can have exactly the same xyz location (since each key only holds one value).  If you have a list of objects that have x, y, and z fields, you can sort it like `sortedByZ = sorted(objects, key = lambda obj: obj.z)`.

Comment: How exactly is the "range of x,y,z cartesian coordinates" that are equivalent defined? Is it some kind of rounding that defines which points are equal? I suggest you "normalize" (e.g. round) your coordinate values before putting them into a tuple for use as a key. Then, when you want to get it back, do the same thing, normalizing the possibly slightly different coordinates to get the same key.

Answer (score 13):

Sure you can, as well as to create single string key for this - just merge string results for your keys like ','.join([k1,k2,k3])

[Read more about dictionaries.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> dictionaries are indexed by keys, which can be any immutable type;
>   strings and numbers can always be keys. Tuples can be used as keys if
>   they contain only strings, numbers, or tuples; if a tuple contains any
>   mutable object either directly or indirectly, it cannot be used as a
>   key. You can’t use lists as keys, since lists can be modified in place
>   using index assignments, slice assignments, or methods like append()
>   and extend().

So you trying to use tuples as a keys and this is OK.

Note that dictionaries in python are not sorted. You can use collections.OrderedDict for this. Also to build correct sorting use [sort/sorted functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with parameter key specified to sort the way you want.

EDITED sample:

```
from itertools import product
myDict = {}
for x,y,z in product(range(10), range(10,20), range(20,30)):
    myDict[(x,y,z)] = sum([x,y,z])
```

Comment: Okay this is helpful. This takes care of the order problem. But I want to use an objects x,y,z coordinates as the key to gain access to another different type of object stored in my dictionary. Im not sure how to enable a wide range of values that will be accepted for each key. Does this make sense?

Comment: @user1846529 you need to provide us a sample of key input and what you need - for me all that you are saying looks ok and should work

Comment: My key will look something like this (1.8,12.3,24.9) and there must a be a range of values that will be accepted for each part of the key. So (1,12,24) would also satisfy the criteria for the key or (2,13,25) could also work...

Comment: @user1846529 as i said python allow you to use tuple as a dictionary key, it is ok that it contains float values, what a real problem you have - to find what?

Comment: Im not sure how to set my key up so it accepts multiple values for each part.

Comment: @user1846529, python is dynamically typed. You don't need to specify ranges for the keys. You just assign them `d[(1.1,2.2,3.3)] = MyObject()`.

Comment: @user1846529 Check my sample please maybe it will help you

Comment: Yeah that is a lot closer to what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @johnthexii You're answer makes sense except I have A LOT of values that could potentially be used as a key and it would be unreasonable to type them all out.

Comment: @user1846529 Ahhh, so you were looking for a way to generate the keys programmatically. If that is the case then Artsiom Rudzenka's loop is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully you will find this useful.

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> def dist(p1, p2):
...     x1, y1, z1 = p1
...     x2, y2, z2 = p2
...     xd = x1 - x2
...     yd = y1 - y2
...     zd = z1 - z2
...     return sqrt((xd ** 2 + yd ** 2 + zd ** 2))
>>> myPoint = (0,0,0)
>>> class MyObject: pass
>>> myDict = {(1,2,3):MyObject(), (4,5,6):MyObject()}
>>> sorted([dist(myPoint, point) for point in myDict])
10: [3.7416573867739413, 8.774964387392123]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you want a possibly unordered collection of mappings from keys (ordered triples) to values (objects). If that's the case, it's very easy to make a composite key out of an ordered triple:

Suppose `obj0` is at x,y,z coordinates `(10,20,30)` and `obj1` is at x,y,z coordinates `(11,21,31)`. Then:

```
myObjects = {(10,20,30): obj0,
             (11,21,31): obj1
            }
```

This works because both `tuple`s and `int`s are immutable types

Hope that helps

Comment: This is close, however I want the objects to accept a wide range of values for each part of the key. For instance, the first part of the key could accept any value ranging from 1 to 100 and the second part could accept any value from 100 to 200. Im not sure how to do that...

Comment: You could just as easily do `{(101,208,35): obj1}`. Are you looking for something that will check the ranges at the time of inserting a new key?

Comment: When I insert a new key I want the dictionary to know that the values inserted are within a specific range that correspond to an object stored in the dictionary.

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: when you insert an object (with its xyz coords as the key) into the dictionary, you want to ensure that its xyz coords are within a certain range. This range is to be determined by the xyz coords of another object already in the dictionary. Is this correct? Let's chat about the spec [in this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19973/complex-dictionary-keys)

Comment: The objects stored in my dictionary are boxes with x,y,z minimum and maximum values. I want the ranges between the minimum and maximum values of x,y,z to be the key. So I then have other objects that are floating around in space randomly, and I want to insert their x,y,z positions into the key so I know which box they are contained in. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm still confused. Let's not clutter the comments. Rather, let's [move this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19973/complex-dictionary-keys), so I'll have a better understanding of what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19975/discussion-between-user1846529-and-inspectorg4dget)

Answer (score 0):

I solved doing this:

```
list = [
         [1,'a','school'],
         [2,'b','church'],
         [3,'c','library'],
         [4,'d','station']
    ]
dic_key = {}
for i in list:
   if (i[0],i[1]) not in dic_key:
      dic_key[i[0],i[1]] = []
   dic_key[i[0],i[1]].append(i[2])

print(dic_key)
```

output: {(1, 'a'): ['school'], (2, 'b'): ['church'], (3, 'c'): ['library'], (4, 'd'): ['station']}